# How remove a specific legend label in the Dataframe.plot?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am trying to plot two DataFrame together by 'bar' style and 'line' style respectively, but have trouble when showing the legend only for the bars, excluding the line.

Here are my codes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'2012':np.random.random_sample((4,)),'2014':np.random.random_sample((4,))})
df.index = ['A','B','C','D']
sumdf = df.T.apply(np.sum,axis=1)
ax = df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
sumdf.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim([-0.5,1.5])
ax.set_ylim([0,3])
ax.legend(loc='upper center',ncol=3,framealpha=0,labelspacing=0,handlelength=4,borderaxespad=0)
```

Annoyingly got this: [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojyub.png), where the line legend is also shown in the legend box. I want to remove it rather than make it invisible.

But I do not find the way.

Thank you!

Comment: settings `sumdf.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)` also works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a [`matplotlib.legend`'s](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) label starts with an underscore, it will not be shown in the legend by default.

You can simply change

```
sumdf.plot(ax=ax)
```

to

```
sumdf.plot(ax=ax, label='_')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What an unintuitive notation!